# Which version of JetBrains Toolbox support Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I was downloading JetBrains Toolbox version 1.22 but its system requirement is Ubuntu 18 or above. I want to install it on Ubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone tell me which version of JetBrains Toolbox is for Ubuntu 16.04 as there are older versions given in their website?